# Is there any guarantee that as task created using task factory will not be scheduled in the UI thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Previously I used to use background worker threads for making service calls and to not block UI thread. Currently started using TPL but ideally tasks should be used for CPU intensive tasks ..

So wondering if there is anything wrong with using task factory for making service calls as there would be many threads which would be sitting idle till the service calls are completed ?

Also as to original question is there any guarantee that a task created will be always be invoked on a thread different from UI thread in a WPF application?

Comment: Why do you say that tasks are only good for CPU intensive tasks?  Also, tasks are always invoked on a thread other than the UI thread unless you specify that the SynchronizationContext is that of the UI thread.  You would also need to avoid using the Dispatcher in your task.

Comment: @Dave Good to know that task would be invoked on different thread than the UI thread.Currently the service calls are synchronous so worried that there would be lot of idle threads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tasks are abstractions for work that is scheduled to run *somehow*. It doesn't have to be CPU intensive.

When you're starting an `async` method from the UI thread, the `SynchronizationContext` is captured and after each `await` the code will execute on the UI thread, unless you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

However, sometimes calling an `async` methods doesn't immediately yield (depending on its implementation), so in those cases to avoid blocking the UI thread, use `Task.Run`.

For example:

```cs
async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   await Task.Run(() => CallServiceAsync());
   // Update UI
}
```

Answer (score 8):

That's what [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) is for. This tells the task scheduler that the task will take a while to complete, so the limited resources of the thread pool won't be used.

As to your actual question, the only possible ways a task will be executed on the UI thread are:

- you use a task scheduler that executes its tasks on the UI thread (such as by using [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx))
- you specify [`TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx) on a task that continues on from a task that executed on the UI thread